# Looking for ANY Linux version with 32 bit ISO to make a LiveUSB

Tags: iso, 32-bit, usb-installation

In order to dedicate an old Thinkpad R-51 to run a distributed computing program called "Folding@Home" it was recommended to do it under Ubuntu 11.04. I am having real problems as follows:

The R51 excludes its CD drive from being bootable. A lot of claims exist online for making a usb-based iso are made but none found so far. The R51 is left with less than 500 mB with Ubuntu 16.04 loaded and runs SLOW

Answer (score 3):

I use Folding@Home on a number of different Ubuntu releases; 11.04 is by no means required, which is fortunate, since this Q&A site *only supports Ubuntu releases* which have not reached End-Of-Community-Support/EndOf-Life, as per https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic (see Questions You Should Avoid).

Those versions are Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 19.10, and 20.04; supported [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are 18.04, 19.10, and 20.04 as [flavours of Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18783/has-lubuntu-16-04-lts-reached-end-of-public-support) (such as Lubuntu) do not have the full five year community support life.

Only one Ubuntu release has a complete desktop 32-bit image, **16.04**: https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso

Once saved on a PC, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu .

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on [another Linux PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu),  on a [Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), or [on a Mac](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos).

Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

Once installed, you can remove the [Unity Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)) and replace it with a [lighter desktop environment](https://www.linuxlinks.com/survey-linux-desktop-environments/3/) or [window manager](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-20-linux-window-managers-a-comprehensive-list-for-linux-users/) such as [fvwm2](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/lnut/ch17_01.htm) which consumes less space, CPU, and memory.

Note: Other, non-Ubuntu 32-bit releases are the province of https://unix.stackexchange.com and you may find [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586003/find-the-lightest-desktop-environment) relevant.